# How to configure spring-boot to send email via sendGrid?

Tags: java, html, spring, email, sendgrid

At the moment I configured my application to send email via spring-mail and my code looks like this:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender sender;
.....
//send email 
MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
                    MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
Template template = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate(templateFileName);
            String html = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, props);    
helper.setTo(to);
helper.setText(html, true);
helper.setSubject(subject);
helper.setFrom(from);
sender.send(message);
```

Now I have task to rewrite it using sendGrid.

I googled this topic and found that java has sendGrid api like [this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/java.html):

```
import com.sendgrid.*;

public class SendGridExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid("SENDGRID_APIKEY");

    SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();

    email.addTo("test@sendgrid.com");
    email.setFrom("you@youremail.com");
    email.setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
    email.setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");

    SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(email);
  }
}
```

Also I've found following class: [SendGridAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sendgrid/SendGridAutoConfiguration.html)
Also I've met following snippet from [there](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

```
# SENDGRID (SendGridAutoConfiguration)
spring.sendgrid.api-key= # SendGrid api key (alternative to username/password).
spring.sendgrid.username= # SendGrid account username.
spring.sendgrid.password= # SendGrid account password.
spring.sendgrid.proxy.host= # SendGrid proxy host.
spring.sendgrid.proxy.port= # SendGrid proxy port.
```

Looks like spring boot has integration with the sendGrid.

But I could not find full example of this integration.
Please share exmple with me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring-Boot autoconfigures `SendGrid` if it's on the classpath.

#### Maven Dependency

Include the library as a maven dependency (see https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java) eg. using gradle:

```
compile 'com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:4.1.2'
```

#### Spring Boot Sendgrid Configuration Properties

Configure the SendGrid Properties (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

```
# SENDGRID (SendGridAutoConfiguration)
spring.sendgrid.api-key= # SendGrid api key (alternative to username/password).
spring.sendgrid.username= # SendGrid account username.
spring.sendgrid.password= # SendGrid account password.
spring.sendgrid.proxy.host= # SendGrid proxy host. (optional)
spring.sendgrid.proxy.port= # SendGrid proxy port. (optional)
```

#### Usage

Spring Boot creates the `SendGrid` Bean automatically.
See https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java for examples on how to use it.

```
class SendGridMailService {

    SendGrid sendGrid;

    public SendGridMailService(SendGrid sendGrid) {
        this.sendGrid = sendGrid;
    }

    void sendMail() {
        Email from = new Email("test@example.com");
        String subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
        Email to = new Email("test@example.com");
        Content content = new Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");
        Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

        Request request = new Request();
        try {
            request.setMethod(Method.POST);
            request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
            request.setBody(mail.build());
            Response response = this.sendGrid.api(request);
            sendGrid.api(request);

            // ...
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify meaning of *spring.sendgrid.proxy.host* ?

Comment: Defaults to `api.sendgrid.com` (see https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sendgrid/SendGrid.java#L79) - but can be overridden if desired.

Comment: When should I use this proxy?

Comment: Whenever you are not able to directly communicate with the outside world. But that depends on your infrastructure. If you don't need it, leave it out.

Comment: My comment above is actually incorrect. I misread the property `proxy.host`. It is actually optional. What i was referring to was the `host` - which defaults to `api.sendgrid.com` but that is not configurable through springs common application properties. However it can be overriden though (for whatever reason).

Comment: I messed a bit. Can you express you thought fully?

Comment: **Whenever you are not able to directly communicate with the outside world. But that depends on your infrastructure. If you don't need it, leave it out** Is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163932/discussion-between-fateddy-and-gstackoverflow).

Comment: additiionally I want to know how to force sendGrid to use SMTP-over-SSL, or SMTP+STARTTLS. Is It enough to use *spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true* ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work this way. This setting is for sending mails through `javax.mail`. Since you are using sendgrid, you have to take a look at their API.

Comment: *For a SSL connections, use port 465.* https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/integrating_with_the_smtp_api.html Do you think is it enough set **spring.sendgrid.proxy.host=465** ?

Comment: The example above uses the v3 API (see here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html). You are now referring to the SMTP API (which has to be used and of course configured in a different way).